# IL code loads Int16 as Int32

Tags: c#, il

This following `C#` code:

```
short first = 1;
short second = 2;
bool eq1 = (first.Equals(second));
```

The code translates to:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // first
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // second
IL_0005:  ldloca.s    00 // first
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // second
IL_0008:  call        System.Int16.Equals
IL_000D:  stloc.2     // eq1
```

`ldloca.s    00` - Load address of local variable with index indx, short form.

`ldloc.1` - Load local variable 1 onto stack.

Why not both of the commands are `ldloca.s`, (both of the variables are of `short` type) ?

Comment: Please note this is not the exact same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511737/int16-bytes-capacity-in-net but rather a specific case question.

Comment: BTW, that `.s` has nothing to do with the `short` type, if that's what's confusing you. (It just means that the variable number is < 256).

Comment: @svick, thanks, it makes it much clearer, I thought it loads the value as an `Int16`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All instance methods on value types have an implicit `this` parameter of type `ref T`, not of type `T`, that's why your `first` variable needs `ldloca`. But `System.Int16.Equals`'s parameter is of type `System.Int16`, without any `ref`, so your `second` variable doesn't need (and cannot be passed with) `ldloca`.

Comment: Which method do you mentioned as _first one needs to use `ldloca`_? I don't get it.

Comment: @SonerGönül The first value, not the first method. Will see if I can reword to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. But I couldn't find anything about _All instance methods on value types have an implicit this parameter of type `ref T`, not of type `T`_ on C# 5.0 specification. Or I didn't see any `ref` usage on [`Int16.Equals(Int16)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/7e0c773f8f59d685.html) method or any other value type methods definition. I'm little bit confused actually. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @SonerGönül Suppose you have `struct S { int i; public void Inc() { ++i; } }`, and `S s = new S();`. After `s.Inc();`, `s.i` is supposed to be `1`, and that isn't possible if the implicit `this` is passed by value, because in that case, the modification to `i` would be made on a copy of the `S` instance, not the original `S` instance. (The CIL specification is more explicit than the C# specification on how this works.)

Comment: Ok. Will check CIL specification also. Thank you.

Comment: Reading this answer after Soner's comments makes it very clear, thanks.

Comment: @IllidanS4 About your edit suggestion, `first` and `second` are marked as code because they're the names of the variables in the question.